# How to select increasing elements of a list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have the following list of tuples:

```
a = [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 4), (5, 2), (6, 8), (7, -1)]
```

I would like to select the elements which second value in the tuple is increasing compared to the previous one. For example I would select `(2, 4)` because `4` is superior to `2`, in the same manner I would select `(4, 4)` and `(6, 8)`.

Can this be done in a more elegant way than a loop starting explicitly on the second element ?

To clarify, I want to select the tuples which second elements are superior to the second element of the prior tuple.

Comment: Please clarify. By "the previous one", do you mean "the first value in that tuple", or "the second value in the tuple prior to this one"?

Comment: Unfortunately I mean the second value of the tuple prior to this one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do this fairly easily:

```
a = [a[i] for i in range(1, len(a)) if a[i][1] > a[i-1][1]]
```

This uses `range(1, len(a))` to start from the second element in the list, then compares the second value in each tuple with the second value from the preceding tuple to determine whether it should be in the new list.

Alternatively, you could use `zip` to generate pairs of neighbouring tuples:

```
a = [two for one, two in zip(a, a[1:]) if two[1] > one[1]]
```

Comment: Magic ! Thanks very much. EDIT: In fact it is not doing what I needed, I need to compare with the second element of the previous tuple. Sorry !

Comment: Thanks, I will accept when I can (I am not the person who downvoted you btw)

Comment: I was the downvoter in this case: it is rarely pythonic to iterate through a `range` in order to index an iterable container.

Comment: Fair comment, I have added a `zip`-based alternative

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [right for left, right in pairwise(a) if right[1] > left[1]]
[(2, 4), (4, 4), (6, 8)]
```

Where `pairwise` is an itertools recipe you can find [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to derive indices and then make list comprehension:

```
a = [t[1] for t in enumerate(a[1:]) if t[1][1] > a[t[0]-1][1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension

```
[i for i in a if (i[0] < i[1])]
```

Returns

```
[(1, 2), (2, 4), (6, 8)]
```

Edit: I was incorrect in my understanding of the question. The above code will return all tuples in which the second element is greater than the first. This is not the answer to the question OP asked.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question; he wants to compare between tuples

Comment: Oh that is my mistake, I must have misunderstood. I interpreted the question as "within the tuple, the second element is greater than the first element". Did they mean that the 2nd element of the tuple is increasing from one tuple to the next?

Comment: The latter; I also initially assumed it was the former!